# How to Compare Column to Count in a Query

Tags: sql, count, group-by, ms-access-2010

I'm not too sophisticated with SQL, I don't know how to compare a count back to a column I'm selecting in a Query in Access. One column is generated as a count that counts IDs, but I want to verify it's correct (compare the column GroupCount with a SQL Count clause)

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
SELECT GroupID, GroupCount, COUNT(*) as A
FROM Table1 GROUP BY GroupID, GroupCount
```

How can I add a where clause that will compare "A" to GroupCount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a `having` in your current query.

```
SELECT GroupID
    ,GroupCount
    ,COUNT(*) AS A
FROM Table1    
GROUP BY GroupID
    ,GroupCount
HAVING COUNT(*) = GroupCount
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, I'm using Access unfortunately. The error message is telling me to enter a parameter value to A, so I think i need to join it back somehow?

Comment: Oh it seems you've updated your answer @soultrain. This is exactly what I need. Thanks!